# Unable to import org.controlsfx

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I'm trying to use `CheckComboBox` from package `org.controlsfx.constrol.*` and when importing the package I get error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol controlsfx
```

I found the API here: http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html

I tried to download the .jar but couldn't find it anywhere, and I'm not using Maven.

Why can't I import it? Or how can I download the jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the latest version of `ControlsFX` can be found on [`Maven Central Repository`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx)

You can also find a download section on the official site - [FXEXPERIENCE](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/)  under the section **Getting ControlsFX**

Comment: Can controlsFX be imported into non-maven Java projects? If so, what's the best way to do it? (Precompiled jar, git submodule, etc)

Comment: You can add the ControlsFX binary into your projects classpath.

Comment: yeap this worked why cant these guys make it be available at the maven repo site mvnrepository.com

Comment: @kinsleykajiva ControlFX is available at mvnrepository.com. Just check out - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx

Comment: ow i see now thanks , maybe i was search it wrong but i have tried looking for it i had to download a jar file to include in my project.Anyways thanks ey.